# Underscore, find and change value in object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am trying to find and replace a value in a function in an object

My object looks like this :

```
 var testStates = [{
    "module": "module1",
    "customUrl": [
        { "mod1": "2" },
        { "mod2": "1" }
    ]
}, {
    "module": "module2",
    "customUrl": [
        { "mod3": "false" },
        { "mod4": "5" }
    ]
}
];
```

And my function is like this :

```
 myFunction = function(mod, name, replace){
 //replace item in testStates
```

}

And basically what i'm trying to do is use those vars to search inside where mod is a "module" value, name is a "mod"'s key (like mod1 or mod2 in the exampels), and replace is the value to replace on that selected mod.

So if i said

```
 myfunction(module1, mod1, 5);
```

I would then want the object to look like

```
    var testStates = [{
    "module": "module1",
    "customUrl": [
        { "mod1": "5" },   ////Changed
        { "mod2": "1" }
    ]
}, {
    "module": "module2",
    "customUrl": [
        { "mod3": "false" },
        { "mod4": "5" }
    ]
}
];
```

Kind of like a find and replace on an object. I'm not sure how to tackle this with underscore, would love some help! Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to pass in the object you want to process, so your function's signature would be:

```
function myfunction (obj, mod, name, replace) {
  // Code
}
```

The idea is simple:
You iterate over the objects in the array, and if the module name is the same as the one you want, then, you check the keys of `customUrl` to find the specified key and replace it with your new value.

Here is the complete function:

```
function myfunction (obj, mod, name, replace) {
  _.each(obj, function(item) {
    if (item.module === mod) {
      _.each(item.customUrl, function(innerItem) {
        if (_.has(innerItem, name)) {
          innerItem[name] = replace;
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

And [here is a jsbin](http://jsbin.com/sorezi/1/) with a simple test too. Click on **Edit in JS Bin** in top right corner and you should see the result in the **console** tab.

Answer (score 1):

Is it really necessary to use underscore? I'd rather do it in pure Javascript. Here, a working example that changes the collection sent.

```
var testStates = [
    {
        "module": "module1",
        "customUrl": [
            { "mod1": "5" },
            { "mod2": "1" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "module": "module2",
        "customUrl": [
            { "mod3": "false" },
            { "mod4": "5" }
        ]
    }
];

var myFunction = function(collection, mod, name, replace){
    var module, customUrl;

    module = collection.filter(function (elem) {
        return elem.module === mod;
    })[0];

    if (!module) {
        return collection;
    }

    customUrl = module.customUrl.filter(function (url) {
        return (typeof(url[name]) !== 'undefined')
    })[0];

    if (!customUrl) {
        return collection;
    }

    customUrl[name] = replace;

    return collection;
}

var returning = myFunction(testStates, 'module2', 'mod4', 'I changed this');

console.log(JSON.stringify(returning));
console.log(JSON.stringify(testStates));
```

Comment: Certainly no need to use it, but I'm using it currently so I wanted to see if I could take advantage of it :)

Comment: Pick what makes the most sense to you and the project, now you have more options and maybe you could run a benchmark and see whats faster and all that. You know, just to show off :D